# Use max column value in order by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, weighting

I'm trying to order a table by two columns, each with a different weighting. The first is `uptime`, which is a value between 0 and 1 and has a weighting of 0.3. The second is `votes`, which is a non-negative integer and has a weighting of 0.7.

The weighting needs to be multiplied by a value between 0-1, so I'm going to get this for votes by dividing the number of votes for each row by the maximum number of votes held by any row.

This is my query so far, and it almost works:

```
SELECT addr
  FROM servers
  ORDER BY (0.3 * uptime) +
           (0.7 * (votes / 100)) DESC
```

The 100 is hard-coded and should be the maximum value of `votes`. Using `MAX(votes)` makes the query return only the record with highest number of votes. Can this be done in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery for selecting the maximum value of `votes`

```
SELECT addr
  FROM servers
  ORDER BY (0.3 * uptime) +
           (0.7 * (votes / (SELECT MAX(votes) FROM servers))) DESC
```

Example fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c1b3/4/0).

Comment: I think he wants to replace `100` by the `MAX(votes)`, and not `votes` for `MAX(votes)`.

Comment: I don't understand why, but on my db this only returns the single row with the most votes. I even tried it from phpmyadmin. Does collation matter?

Comment: @Matt Can you edit my fiddle to show an excerpt of your data and verify your error there?

Comment: Oops dumb mistake, my real table was named with a prefix and I didn't change this in the subquery. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Define a variable and use it:

```
DECLARE @maxVotes int
SELECT @maxVotes = MAX(votes) from servers

SELECT addr
  FROM servers
  ORDER BY (0.3 * uptime) +
           (0.7 * (votes / @maxVotes)) DESC
```

or use a subquery in the `order by`:

```
SELECT addr
  FROM servers
  ORDER BY (0.3 * uptime) +
           (0.7 * ( votes / (SELECT MAX(votes) FROM servers))) DESC
```